# Exception thrown when calling getFriends

Tags: java, android, android-simple-facebook

I get this exception, "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()", thrown when I call either get or getFriends. Here is the code I use for getFriends. It is called from the main thread.

```
public void returnFriendIDs(final int pointer){
    Properties properties = new Properties.Builder()
                .add(Profile.Properties.ID)
                .add(Profile.Properties.FIRST_NAME)
                .add(Profile.Properties.LAST_NAME)
                .add(Profile.Properties.INSTALLED)
                .build();

    try{
        mSimpleFacebook.getFriends(properties,  new OnFriendsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {
                String resultStr = "";
                Log.d(LOGPREFIX, "Number of friends = " + friends.size());
                for(Profile p : friends){
                    resultStr += p.getId()+',';
                }
                if(friends.size() > 0) returnFriends(pointer, resultStr.substring(0,resultStr.length()-1));
                else returnFriends(pointer, "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(String reason){
                returnFriends(pointer, "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Throwable throwable){
                Log.w(LOGPREFIX, throwable.getMessage());
                returnFriends(pointer, "");
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Throwable throwable){
        Log.w(LOGPREFIX, "In getFriends"+throwable.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I've tried calling Looper.prepare() before calling getFriends, but that just leads to none of the callbacks ever getting called.

My onActivityResult function is

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        //Log.w(LOGPREFIX, "onActivityResult() called.");
        mSimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Handle InApp Purchase call results
        if(REQUEST_INAPP_PURCHASE == requestCode)
        {
             if (!mBillingHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
             }
        }
    }
```

The stacktrace is:

```
Pending exception java.lang.RuntimeException thrown by 'unknown throw location'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
  at void android.os.Handler.<init>(android.os.Handler$Callback, boolean) (Handler.java:200)
  at void android.os.Handler.<init>() (Handler.java:114)
  at void com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask.onPreExecute() (RequestAsyncTask.java:146)
  at android.os.AsyncTask android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, java.lang.Object[]) (AsyncTask.java:587)
  at android.os.AsyncTask android.os.AsyncTask.execute(java.lang.Object[]) (AsyncTask.java:535)
  at void com.sromku.simple.fb.actions.GetAction.runRequest(com.facebook.Request) (GetAction.java:143)
  at void com.sromku.simple.fb.actions.GetAction.executeImpl() (GetAction.java:81)
  at void com.sromku.simple.fb.actions.AbstractAction.execute() (AbstractAction.java:17)
  at void com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook.getFriends(com.sromku.simple.fb.entities.Profile$Properties, com.sromku.simple.fb.listeners.OnFriendsListener) (SimpleFacebook.java:594)
  at void com.fillmyblank.app.FillMyBlank.returnFriendIDs(int) (FillMyBlank.java:325)
  at void org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.nativeInit() (SDLActivity.java:-2)
  at void org.libsdl.app.SDLMain.run() (SDLActivity.java:509)
  at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:818)
```

It is called with this code from my main function(which I believe is the UI thread). I use the ndk so by main function I mean the actual function main.

```
    aEnv = (JNIEnv *)SDL_AndroidGetJNIEnv();

    aActivityClass = aEnv->FindClass(mClassPath.c_str());

    aStaticMid = aEnv->GetStaticMethodID(aActivityClass, "GetActivity", "()Lcom/fillmyblank/app/FillMyBlank;");
    aActivity =  aEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(aActivityClass, aStaticMid);

    friends* fp = new friends;
    fp->waiting = SDL_CreateCond();

    aJavaMethodID = aEnv->GetMethodID(aActivityClass, "returnFriendIDs", "(I)V");

    aEnv->CallVoidMethod(aActivity, aJavaMethodID, fp);
```

EDIT: Added stacktrace

EDIT: Added the calling function.

Comment: Please provide exception stacktrace

Comment: Added into the question

Comment: What's the point of OnActivityResult()? I see no connection to returnFriendIDs(). You say returnFriendIDs() is called from the "main" thread. What does that mean? Did you create a thread which you feel is the "main" thread? Or do you mean the UI thread? "main" thread is meaningless without context.

Comment: Also, can you explain getFriends() a bit more. Based on the code you've posted, you are calling getFriends() and passing in a new handler. This suggests that getFriends() action runs in a different thread than whichever one is calling getFriendIDs().

Comment: I am using the ndk almost completely for development so by main thread I mean the thread the function main runs on which I believe is the UI thread. Since the callbacks are run in async I use the returnFriends method to signal when it is done to the main thread so it can retrieve the data
I included onActivityResult because it was suggested to me that not having that correct could cause the problem with it never executing.

Comment: We need more contextual code, like how and where is called `returnFriendIDs`. I'm pretty sure it's not called from the main thread.

Comment: It is called from the main thread at least I think CallVoidMethod calls it in the same thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The explanation

The Exception is thrown in the **`onPreExecute`** part of an `AsyncTask` which is part of the Facebook library (`com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask`).

`onPreExecute` is executed in the same thread as the caller of the AsyncTask. If the caller is the ui thread, no issue, it will work. It the caller is not the ui thread, it could fail (there is a great chance). If any component of the ui or related to the ui is used, it will fail.

In your case, it is not executed in the ui thread but in in a regular thread which does not have a message loop so this famous Exception is thrown : `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

### The solution

You have to use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method that will ensure that your code is executed in the ui thread. `runOnUiThread` takes a `Runnable` as a parameter.

```
public void returnFriendIDs(final int pointer)
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Properties properties = new Properties.Builder()
            .add(Profile.Properties.ID)
            .add(Profile.Properties.FIRST_NAME)
            .add(Profile.Properties.LAST_NAME)
            .add(Profile.Properties.INSTALLED)
            .build();

            try{
                mSimpleFacebook.getFriends(properties,  new OnFriendsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {
                        String resultStr = "";
                        Log.d(LOGPREFIX, "Number of friends = " + friends.size());
                        for(Profile p : friends){
                            resultStr += p.getId()+',';
                        }
                        if(friends.size() > 0) returnFriends(pointer, resultStr.substring(0,resultStr.length()-1));
                        else returnFriends(pointer, "");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFail(String reason){
                        returnFriends(pointer, "");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onException(Throwable throwable){
                        Log.w(LOGPREFIX, throwable.getMessage());
                        returnFriends(pointer, "");
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(Throwable throwable){
                Log.w(LOGPREFIX, "In getFriends"+throwable.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```